# awk: print the average of each students along with the given details using different separator

Tags: linux, unix, awk

File which named as `Input.txt` has following data as name, class, schoolName, marks1 and marks2 with `#` separator:

```
Deepu#First#Meridian#95#90
Neethu#Second#Meridian#80#75
Sethu#First#DAV#75#70
Theekshana#Second#DAV#80#79
Teju#First#Sangamithra#88#63
Theekshita#Second#Sangamithra#91#90
```

Using above file print all the details along with average using `|` separator as output.

My answer:

```
awk 'OFS="|" { avg=0; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){avg=($4+$5)/2;} print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,avg}' Input.txt
```

I tried one more command as:

```
awk 'OFS="|" {sum=0; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,sum/(NF-2)}' Input.txt
```

Output looks like this:[image: Output image]

Please help me out to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set FS in the BEGIN, the below works for me

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="#"} {avg=0; for(i=0;i<NR;i++) avg=($4 + $5)/2.0;}{OFS="|"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,avg}'

$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="#"} {avg=0; for(i=0;i<NR;i++) avg=($4 + $5)/2.0;}{OFS="|"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,avg}' mehdi.txt
Deepu|First|Meridian|95|90|92.5
Neethu|Second|Meridian|80|75|77.5
Sethu|First|DAV|75|70|72.5
Theekshana|Second|DAV|80|79|79.5
Teju|First|Sangamithra|88|63|75.5
Theekshita|Second|Sangamithra|91|90|90.5

$
```

Thanks @EdMorton. This can be further shortened as

```
$ awk ' BEGIN { FS="#";OFS="|"} {$6=($4 + $5)/2.0;$0=$0;print $0 }' mehdi.txt
Deepu|First|Meridian|95|90|92.5
Neethu|Second|Meridian|80|75|77.5
Sethu|First|DAV|75|70|72.5
Theekshana|Second|DAV|80|79|79.5
Teju|First|Sangamithra|88|63|75.5
Theekshita|Second|Sangamithra|91|90|90.5

$
```

Comment: Rather than setting OFS half way through processing every line of input just set it once in the BEGIN section. Also the loop repeating the same calculation multiple times for every line of input makes no sense at all - if you removed `avg=0; for(i=0;i<NR;i++)` you'd get the same output.

Comment: @EdMorton.. I just corrected OP's attempt in one of his answer.. Tiw's answer is right way

Comment: `$0=$0` I think it's superfluous, when you assign `$6` the line separator will be automatically changed.

Comment: @Tiw is right. `$0=$0` will re-split $0 into fields $1, etc. but you don't use any fields afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this more concise way:

```
awk -F# '{$(NF+1)=($4+$5)/2}1' OFS='|'
```

Eg:

```
$ awk -F# '{$(NF+1)=($4+$5)/2}1' OFS='|' Input.txt
Deepu|First|Meridian|95|90|92.5
Neethu|Second|Meridian|80|75|77.5
Sethu|First|DAV|75|70|72.5
Theekshana|Second|DAV|80|79|79.5
Teju|First|Sangamithra|88|63|75.5
Theekshita|Second|Sangamithra|91|90|90.5
```

Comment: Yup, that's the way to do it!

Comment: You know the number of fields so no need to use NF. awk -F# '{$6=($4+$5)/2}1' OFS='|'

Comment: @ctac_  Yeah, thought about that. Just in case there're other columns in OP's true data, so I showed this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F#  'OFS="|" {avg=($4+$5/2);gsub(/#/,"|");print $0,avg}' Input.txt
```

This will do it without needing to iterate through the first part of the string.  It does a substitution of the "#" with a "|" on the whole line, and then simply prints the average after reprinting the line with format desired and the output delimiter.

Comment: @Tiw the OP isn't assigning to any field so she actually does need the gsub() to change the field separators but then the `OFS="|"` is superfluous (as well as being in a conditional part of the script instead of in the BEGIN section where it belongs).

Comment: @EdMorton  Yeah, you're right, I thought about those together, missed this. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

After using FS in the command:

```
awk 'FS="#" {avg=0; for(i=0;i<NR;i++) avg=($4 + $5)/2;}{OFS="|"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,avg}' Input.txt
```

I get the desired output but in output, average of first row is displayed as zero and OFS is also not applied here. Can any one tell me about this?

Output looks like this:[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbZ8m.png)

Comment: wrap the ````FS="#"```` in the BEGIN block. Check my answer

Comment: Put everything related to your question inside your question. this isn't an answer so delete it.